# Arbol no anidado JSON en Angular + PrimeNg

Tags: json, angular, primeng, jstree

Esta es la primera vez que lanzo una pregunta y espero no meter mucho la pata.

Tenemos un árbol no anidado dentro de un JSON, es decir, es un listado de elementos que tienen un identificador único y un identificador para encontrar al elemento padre. Es necesario representarlo en pantalla y preferiría hacerlo con [PrimeNG](https://www.primefaces.org/primeng/#/tree), pero no encuentro la forma. Sí que he visto que es posible con [NgJsTree](https://ezraroi.github.io/ngJsTree/)

Un ejemplo del JSON sería

```
    [
    {
        "id": "1",
        "parent": "#",
        "label": "Padre 1"
    },
    {
        "id": "2",
        "parent": "#",
        "label": "Padre 2"
    },
    {
        "id": "3",
        "parent": "2",
        "label": "Hijo 1"
    },
    {
        "id": "4",
        "parent": "2",
        "label": "Hijo 2"
    }
]
```

Y esto se mostraría de la siguiente forma

- Padre 1
- Padre 2

  - Hijo 1
  - Hijo 2

¿Sabéis si es posible?

Por estudios de rendimiento, sabemos que esta estructura es la más eficiente. El arbol puede tener más varias docenas de miles de nodos y profundidad N.

Tiene que cargarse completa en el navegador para diversas funcionalidades. Retrabajar el arbol no es una opción porque acarrearía grandes pérdidas de rendimiento.

Funciona y bien con NgJsTree, pero me gustaría usar algo con soporte a largo plazo y el uso de PrimeNG es obligatorio.

Comment: ¿Por qué no procesar el objeto para obtener la estructura que necesitas o que veas más cómodo para trabajar con ella?

Answer (score 0):

```
<p-table [columns]="cols" [value]="cars">
    <ng-template pTemplate="header" let-columns>
        <tr>
            <th *ngFor="let col of columns">
                {{col.header}}
            </th>
        </tr>
    </ng-template>
    <ng-template pTemplate="body" let-rowData let-columns="columns">
        <tr>
            <td *ngFor="let col of columns">
                    {{rowData[col.field]}}
            </td>
        </tr>
    </ng-template>
</p-table>
```

Comment: Hola, explica como funciona tu código y como resuelve la problematica del usuario. Si no la respuesta será tomada como de mala calidad.

Comment: Si entiendo bien esta aproximación, se está pintando una tabla. Lo que necesitamos es pintar un árbol con nodos que se puedan contraer o expandir.